# Is alias construction of shared_ptr from void safe?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

This is an entirely hypothetical question about `shared_ptr` aliasing constructor and UB.

Lets imagine a situation where we store `std::shared_ptr<void>` in some database. Lets also imagine that we can safely cast a `void *` pointing to an instance of a parent type `A` to a pointer of a child type `B` (ex. via a compile-time generated proxy).

Will the following situation result in UB, or is it safe?

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<void> sp_v = get_vp(); // sp_v points to an instance of parent type `A`
B *ptr_b = cast_to_b(sp_v.get());      // Safe cast of `void *` aliasing `A *` to `B *` via a proxy.

std::shared_ptr<B> sp_b = std::shared_ptr<B>{sp_v, ptr_b}; // <- Potential UB here?
```

From what i assume, there should be no UB, as aliasing constructor should only share the control block, however i am not sure if there are any implementation-defined edge cases or STL definition quirks here that might result in UB.

Comment: I suppose that by "storing in some database" you do not mean to persist the binary data of the shared_ptr, are you?

Comment: There's also [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) which will be safer than big hammer casting a `void*`.

Comment: @PhilMasteG no, i just mean that the `shared_ptr` is stored somewhere else :)

Comment: @Eljay yes, std::any is safer but sadly it does not allow for plymorphic casts and does not do reference counting. It is also dubiously useful in shared libraries since it is using c++ RTTI which has issues with shared objects and DLLs. besides, this is just a theoretical question :)

Comment: As @Goswin answered, the `shared_ptr` bits here are fine, however I have great confidence that `cast_to_b` is horribly broken.  There is no upcast, downcast, or crosscast that works with a type-erased (`void*`) input.

Comment: @BenVoigt such a cast could work if `cast_to_b` would be a compile-time generated funtor that would internally cast `void *` to `A *`, then downcast to `B *` anr return it. You would not be casting `void *` directly, for course.

Comment: @JustClaire: Correct, it has to know to reinterpret_cast the incoming pointer to `A*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr:

> ... such as in the typical use cases where ptr is a member of the object managed by r or is an alias (e.g., downcast) of r.get() ...

So this is exactly the envisioned use case.

Comment: Thank you, i must have missed that completely :D